# Modify the source code of contacts application on an Android

Tags: android, contacts, smartphone

I want to know if it's possible to customize the default contact application because I want to write a better one. One that gives a ranking of the contacts in a particular user context (based on location, time, day, recent calls...). I want to give a list of 10 contacts which will probably be called. I've read that some internal classes in the application are not public and not in the SDK API's. So is there another way? I also started to write my own application and it's easy to get the contacts and make the design. But is it possible to make calls in it?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, technically it is possible to modify the Contacts application, but it requires you to download the source. All of the source to the original Contacts application is on the [documentation web site](http://source.android.com/). Download the source, find the application and modify what you desire to modify. To address your issue about some of the class not being public, I'm sure you can figure it out. I can't imagine the functionality from those classes would be too hard to reproduce (unless they are core classes).

Comment: Thx, but is it possible to delete the default contact application from your smartphone and using mine instead?

Comment: Yes, but you will need root access. In the mean time, it is just easier to use yours of the stock one.